# Searching specific service provide by Web API in local network using DiscoveryClient in c#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, service-discovery

I need to discovery automatically where is a service (provided by a WEB API - RESTFULL) in a local network.

My idea is to use the DiscoveryClient for that, but I just found some examples to WCF.

Anybody can help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

`DiscoveryClient` uses `WS-Discovery` protocol which is a SOAP-based protocol.

Discovery in REST is normally implemented through Hypermedia. Or you can have a custom registry service for it.